# chromium kiosk terminal options

Tags: raspberry-pi, chromium

I'm using a Raspberry PI 3 with chromium and kiosk. If I start chromium as normal, I can enable kiosk and set specific options, namely hide cursor, disable context menu, disable image drag, disable text selection and prevent sleeping.

If I start from terminal using `chromium-browser --kiosk http://www.website.com` the browser starts up in kiosk mode, but with none of these options set.

What I want is to be able to start chromium when the PI boots with all these options configured. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Note! this answer is for raspbian OS

You can create an autostart file

`~/.config/autostart/autoChromium.desktop`

With this content

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=/usr/bin/chromium-browser --noerrdialogs --disable-session-crashed-bubble --disable-infobars --kiosk http://www.website.com
Hidden=false
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
Name[en_US]=AutoChromium
Name=AutoChromium
Comment=Start Chromium when GNOME starts
```

This will autostart chromium in kiosk mode when you boot